# Android, XAMARIN: Check if view is visible in a recyclerview and react to event

Tags: android, xamarin

I have a recyclerview with some elements in it. Some of which are supposed to start a little animation once they become visible.
In an activity with a scollview, I simply overrode "`OnWindowFocusChange(Bool hasFocus)"` to check for visibility. However, this doesnt exist in a recview.

How would I do this in a recyclerview?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a OnScrollListener like this:

```
_myRecyclerView.AddOnScrollListener(new MyOnScrollListener());
```

Your custom listener can be implemented like @Prem showed in Java.

```
public class MyOnScrollListener : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener
{
    public override void OnScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy)
    {
        //rest of the code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this use [**RecyclerView.addOnScrollListener**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.OnScrollListener.html#RecyclerView.OnScrollListener())

```
RecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

            int firstpos = horizontalLayoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
            int lastpos = horizontalLayoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();



        }

    });
```

- [**`int findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition ()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html#findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition())

  > Returns the adapter position of the first fully visible view. This position does not include adapter changes that were dispatched after the last layout pass.
- [**`int findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition ()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html#findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition())

  > Returns the adapter position of the last fully visible view. This position does not include adapter changes that were dispatched after the last layout pass.

Comment: hi and thanks son goku ;) but this is java - i am coding in xamarin = c#...

Comment: @innomotionmedia i know you to use same logic in `C#`

Comment: i am trying to adapt that but at the moment it is a bit too much for me :D i am still a noob ;)